# How to get and build only storm tar from hdp?

Tags: apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to get only storm tar from hdp rather than getting the entire bundle which includes hadoop tar and many other tars. Is there any way to get only storm tar?

The only way I have found till now is to clone the repository
https://github.com/hortonworks/storm-release/tree/HDP-2.6.5.3002-10-tag and then manually build storm. Is there any other way to get storm tar out of hdp?